# Final object in the "free group" category $\mathscr{F}^A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, free-groups

The following excerpts come from the book **Algebra: Chapter 0**'s section II.5 - Free groups.  My question is about an easy exercise.

1. First, to define the free group $F(A)$ on $A$, the author introduces a category $\mathscr{F}^A$ as follows:

   [image]
2. The exercise is 5.1 at the end of the section, which is shown below.

   [image]
3. In the main text, the author proved that free group $F(A)$ on A will be (the group component of) an initial object in $\mathscr{F}^A$. The universal property is stated as follows:

   [image]
4. When $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton. The author **find** this function $j: \{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$  which sends $a$ to $1$, as an qualified initial object.

My attempt is also to consider the simplest situation when $A = \{a\}$. As the following diagram shows:

[image]

If $F(A)$ above is a final object, then we can find a set-function $j: A \rightarrow F(A)$ such that for all groups $G$ and set-functions $f: {a} \rightarrow G$ there exists an unique group homomorphism $\varphi: G \rightarrow F(A)$ such that the above diagram commutes.

Because the diagram must commute, I have to **force** $j(a) = \varphi \circ f(a)$. Because this property holds for all $f$'s, let me make $f(a)=1_G$. Because $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism,
I have to **force** $\varphi(1_G)  = \varphi \circ f(a) = 1_{F(A)}  = j(a)$.

Then, I find I can't do any **'force'** anymore, which means I can find many $\varphi$ satisfying the above requirements. For the specific function $f(a)=1_G$, $\varphi$  is not unique. So there is no such final object.

My question is:

1. I only proved when $A= \{a\}$ is a singleton, there are no final objects. Is there a situation when $A$ is larger, the case is true?
2. Maybe there is some generalization behind this exercise? I chose a very special function $f(a)=1_G$. If there is, could someone please indicate to me what kind of generalization it is?

Comment: Which textbook is this from?

Comment: @Shaun sorry, I just added.

Comment: Consider the object $(j,E)$, where $E$ is the trivial group and $j:A\to E$ the only possible map.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you! You are right. My proof is wrong and the object $(j,E)$ should be the final object.